# Is it possible to move an object, vertex, light. camera etc by a set amount?

Tags: transforms

Sorry for the very basic question, it's my first ever.  Have used 3dsmax for ages and am really keen to transition to Blender but I'm finding it a steep learning curve.

In 3dsmax I was always able to move/rotate/scale something using typed in values in the 'Transform Type' dialogue box. This would enable you to precisely transform almost anything either by typing in a value for let's say the x co-ordinate in world space or by moving it relative to its current position (which they call offset:screen)

I can't work out how to do both in Blender though.
Say I add a cube to the scene.  Then move it 6000mm along the x axis.  The cube is then at 6000,0,0. All good.
In max, if I then want to move the cube incrementally, say 4mm further along the x axis, I could just type 4 into the x box of the offset:screen bit which would move it along 4mm to 6004,0,0

Is there an equivalent to 'offset:screen' in Blender?
Closest I can find is 'Delta transform in the object properties.  typing 4 into the x box will move the cube 4mm along which would put it at 6004,0,0 but the huge issue then is that Blender says the cube's x location is still 6000 rather than 6004.  This would cause all sorts of confusion.

Is it possible to upload a screenclip to demonstrate what I'm trying to achive?

Thanks

Comment: g x 4 enter.  Or, enter values in transform (look in properties/object, or sidebar/item.)  You can use math in fields: click in there, type "+ 4", enter.  Or, open the operator panel after a move operation and adjust fields there.  "Is it possible to upload a screenclip" You can include .GIFs in your question if you want, same as any other image; I drag-and-drop into the editing box to do so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get a similar behavior in Blender:

1. Double-click the transform field
2. Type in the value you want to add (+2,-2, whatever number)
3. Hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much. That's really useful. I can now continue my journey into Blenderworld!

Comment: Happy to help, good luck with your project :)